AzureDevOps- Automating Branch Pipeline: Task State Check in work item
I need to automate the branch pipeline to perform the following steps:

Check the status of a specific task ID.
If the task ID is "closed," reopen it and set its status to "active."
Proceed with the next stage in the pipeline deployment.
Once the deployment is completed, close the task ID again.

How to accomplish this?
Using the gate and invoking the rest API (Patch) to update (Active / Close)  the work item

Have you tried something? What happened?

Hi @Alok Ranjan, what's the latest state of the issue? Have you tried the gates shared by me?

You can refer to the following yaml. It uses REST API Work Items - Get Work Item to get the state of the work item and uses Work Items - Update to update the state.
variables:
  workitemid: {Your target work item id}

trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

stages:
- stage: stageA
  jobs:
  - job: jobA
    steps:
    - task: PowerShell@2
      displayName: Check the state of target work item
      name: MyOutputVar
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          $header = @{'Authorization' = 'Bearer ' + "$(System.AccessToken)"}
          
          # Get the work item
          $url = "$(System.CollectionUri)$(System.TeamProjectId)/_apis/wit/workitems/$(workitemid)?api-version=7.1-preview.3"
          $workItem = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers $header -ContentType "application/json" -Method Get
          
          # Check the state of the work item
          if ($workItem.fields.'System.State' -eq "Closed") {
          # If the state is "Closed", change it to "Active"
          $body = @'
          [
            {
            "op": "add",
            "path": "/fields/System.State",
            "value": "Active"
            }
          ]
          '@
          # Update the work item
          Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers $header -ContentType "application/json-patch+json" -Body $body -Method Patch
          } else {
            Write-Host "The stage of work item is" $workItem.fields.'System.State'
          }
- stage: stageB
  jobs:
  - job: Job1
    steps:
      - script: echo Running Stage B
      - task: PowerShell@2
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          script: |
            $header = @{'Authorization' = 'Bearer ' + "$(System.AccessToken)"}
            $url = "$(System.CollectionUri)$(System.TeamProjectId)/_apis/wit/workitems/$(workitemid)?api-version=7.1-preview.3"
            $body = @'
            [
                {
                  "op": "add",
                  "path": "/fields/System.State",
                  "value": "Closed"
                }
            ]
            '@
            Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers $header -ContentType "application/json-patch+json" -Body $body -Method Patch
            


Update: Using gates to run REST API

Create a Generic service connection



Add a variable workitemid in your release



Add Invoke REST API gate to check the state of your target WI.



Connection type: Generic
Generic service connection: The service connection created at step1.
Method: GET
Headers:

{
"Content-Type":"application/json", 
"Authorization": "Bearer $(system.AccessToken)"
}


URL suffix and parameters: /$(System.TeamProjectId)/_apis/wit/workitems/$(workitemid)?api-version=7.1-preview.3
Advanced->Success criteria: eq(root['fields']['System.State'], 'Closed')


Add the second Invoke REST API gate to update the state of your target WI.


Method: PATCH
Headers:

{
"Content-Type":"application/json-patch+json", 
"Authorization": "Bearer $(system.AccessToken)"
}


Body:

[
  {
     "op": "add",
     "path": "/fields/System.State",
     "value": "Active"
  }
]


Advanced->Success criteria: eq(root['fields']['System.State'], 'Active')
Others are the same as above.



Thanks so much and I will give a try and let you know !

Feel free to let me know if there is any issue on your side.

Hi Ziyang - How we could achieve this though the Azure Devops UI -  We do,not have to use the yaml just want to use the Azure Devops UI

What do you mean by saying "use the Azure Devops UI"? Do you want to use classic pipeline or something else?

I was actually trying using the Classic pipeline using gates for pre-deployment condition -I am going through the link -  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/deploy-using-approvals?view=azure-devops.. In this URL step 4 - You could see ( Screenshot)  there is option to invoke REST API ( probably we could use to re-open the closed work item using the API )

You can do it using gates, but you need to ensure the state of your target work item is "Closed" to start the first deployment. Otherwise, the deployment will never start since it doesn't meet the condition "update the WI when the state is Closed". See my update above.

By the way, don't forget to add a powershell task and run REST API to change the state back to "Closed" in the last step of your deployment. Go to powershell task's Control Options->Run this task->Select Even if a previous task has failed, even if the deployment was canceled. Then this step can ensure the state of your WI is "Closed". Otherwise, if the deployment fails, the task cannot be run and you cannot proceed with the next deployment. Unless you manually change the state again.

Yes, I was thinking the same , if the deployment failed then thinking to close the item manually ..

Hi @Alok Ranjanm, have you tried the gates shared by me? Did it work for you?

Hi @ Ziyang Liu-MSF- Sorry I was not well so did not replied you. I was having the access issue so got resolved. Iwill try and let you know asap.

Hi@ZiyangLiu-MSFT - I have tried but it not working - Even I tried with the post method as well . Also its not giving me any error logs as well.

Exception Message: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. (type WebException)
Evaluation of expression 'eq(root['fields']['System.State'], 'Active')' failed.
Getting the below error- Try changing the PAT to  to be base64 string but not working
Exception Message: Error parsing API response into a JSON object. (type DistributedTaskException)


Did the first API used to check your work item work? 2. Is your target work item in the same project as the release pipeline or in a different project? If it's in a different project, you need to replace $(System.TeamProjectId) with your target project id. Also, go to Project Settings ->Pipelines -> turn off Limit job authorization scope to current project for release pipelines. 3. Have you created a Generic service connection as shown in my screenshot? 4. Add a variable system.debug in your release pipeline. Then trigger a release and check if there is any detailed info.



Did the first API used to check your work item work? -Yes2. Is your target work item in the same project as the release pipeline or in a different project?- Yes  go to Project Settings ->Pipelines -> turn off Limit job authorization scope to current project for release pipelines.- Okay -  3. Have you created a Generic service connection as shown in my screenshot?  Yes and kept my org name and project as well. will do...


I have just created powershell task and and it work fine ( using PAT) ..But now requirement has bit changed and without the PAT and without the REST API how we could approach the same task .Please suggest

Can you share a screenshot of your second Invoke REST API gate, which is used to update work item? The above two Invoke REST API gates work without any issue on my side.

"without the REST API" - Do you mean that you don't want to use Invoke REST API gate anymore?

Yes, I have used the power shell task and used as you have mentioned ealrlier - $header = @{'Authorization' = 'Bearer ' + "$(System.AccessToken)"} . It works fine. Thank you so much !

It's great to know my solutions can help you. Feel free to let me you if you have any question related to my answer.
